# What causes "Unknown chromium error: -400"?

Tags: android, webview

I'm receiving an error when trying to load a URL in a WebView.

What causes "Unknown chromium error: -400"?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I see that I forgot `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>` Whoops.