# Website not loading in WebView

Tags: android, android-webview

After reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7305089/android-how-to-load-external-webpage-inside-webview) post, I thought it would be plain sailing adding a `WebView` of one of my web pages. But how wrong i was, I can only assume the problem is due to scripting, but here is my code

```
    @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.layout);

    WebView mv = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView);
    mv.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

    final Activity activity = this;

    mv.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
            Toast.makeText(activity, description + " (" + errorCode + ") " + failingUrl, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            Toast.makeText(activity, url, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }
    });
    mv.loadUrl("http://www.google.co.uk");

}
```

The code builds and runs, but the web page does not load i get an error code of -1 back and see the below line the logcat.

```
 01-11 14:46:55.362: D/chromium(22438): Unknown chromium error: -400
```

I have internet permission as another part of my application uses adverts and they are fine.

Comment: try using some another `URL`.

Comment: try to print out `Error Info Return inside onReceivedError() into-->logcat`

Comment: These link may help you but as you already stated tht u added proper permission still have look @ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9367973/what-causes-unknown-chromium-error-400

Comment: Its just -1, the description being "Error". It is acting like there is no internet connection, though other parts of the app are fine.

Answer (score 0):

Your implementation of shouldOverrideUrlLoading is confuses me. Why do you call loadUrl?
Try to change to this:

```
@Override
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
   Toast.makeText(activity, url, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
   return super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, url);
}
```

Comment: Only because others have reported doing so works. See the link in OP.

Answer (score -3):

Please check if you didn't forget to add :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

in you AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: Read the question, mate